# --noconsole not working with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, wkhtmltopdf

When I run my program using `python myprogram.py`, it runs as intended and no command prompt pops up. When I create an executable using `pyinstaller myprogram.py -F --noconsole`, a blank command prompt pops up. The title of this command prompt is the location of the wkhtmltopdf.exe program used within myprogram.py. I don't think the issue is with wkhtmltopdf though since the command prompt doesn't show up when I run `python myprogram.py`. I think it's something with pyinstaller, but I thought using the --noconsole option would prevent this. I've also tried --windowed.

Comment: Have you tried to use `-w` flag instead? What Python and Pyinstaller versions? Also try to use `-w` flag before `-F` like `pyinstaller myprogram.py -w -F`

Comment: I'm using Python version 3.6.5 and Pyinstaller version 3.3.1. I just reran it using `pyinstaller myprogram.py -w -F` and the command prompt still pops up

Comment: Works for me with PyInstaller 3.4. My program uses PySide2 and shows GUI window. Without `-w` flag, both GUI and console windows are shown. With it, GUI only.

Answer (score 3):

When you run PyInstaller on your project, does a .SPEC file also appear?

If so, edit the .SPEC file's exe field like so:

```
exe = EXE(
      ...,
      console=False,
      ...
      )
```

Then run PyInstaller on the .SPEC file.

If a .SPEC file didn't appear before, try running PyInstaller on your project without any parameters (so just `pyinstaller myProgram.py`). A .SPEC file should appear and you can edit it as above and then rerun PyInstaller.

Comment: A .SPEC file appeared the first time I ran it and console was already set to False. I  still went ahead and ran pyinstaller on the .SPEC file itself, but the command prompt still shows up. When I run pyinstaller on the .SPEC file is the executable that's created in the same location as when I run it on the program itself (The dist folder)?

Comment: @Delphinidae Yes, the executable is in the dist/myProjectName folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion on this:
comment out all print statements.
Keep it simple, like so:

```
pyinstaller --onefile  --noconsole <filename>.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having lots of trouble getting the `noconsole` or `windowed` options to work on my Windows 10 machine.

I started with the `.spec` file generated by PyInstaller.
Somehow it had the line:
`[('v', None, 'OPTION')],` in the `EXE` section.
When I commented that out, and added the nonconsole and windowed options, it worked!
Here is the working section:

```
       a.scripts,
       # [('v', None, 'OPTION')],
       exclude_binaries=True,
       name='my program name',
       debug=False,
       bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=False,
          windowed=True)
```

I can only guess that the offending line stopped PyInstaller from processing the rest of the `EXE` statement, and so it missed the options.