# How to prevent console when running pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I am trying to prevent a console/terminal screen from appearing when I click on the executable file generated from pyinstaller.

I am currently using MacOS, and I tried `--windowed` or `--noconsole` but it returned the following error:

```
option(s) not allowed:
  --console/--nowindowed/--windowed/--noconsole
```

Tried online solutions such as changing the extension from `.py` to `.pyw` but it doesn't work as well.

In my spec file, I have specified `console=False,` but the terminal still appears. I am currently using MacOS, python 3.11 and pyinstaller 6.1.0!

Does anyone have a fix? Thank you!

**spec file**

```
a = Analysis(
['/path/to/main.py'],
pathex=[],
binaries=[],
datas=[
    ('path/to/file', '.')
    ],
hiddenimports=[],
hookspath=[],
hooksconfig={},
runtime_hooks=[],
excludes=[],
noarchive=False,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Main App',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='main.icns',
)
```

Comment: could you also post the command/spec file you use to build?

Comment: As MacOs is a Unix like, try `your_command   1> /dev/null 2>& 1`  [redirecting to /dev/null](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563563/372108) (`rm` is only an example of command in the link)

Comment: @Raphael my command would be ‘pyinstaller /path/to/specfile.py’

Comment: @thompsonrapier have you tried this: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-macos-bundle
It would be great if you could post the entire spec file (or a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for the link. I have looked at it, and not sure which one I should include. Nonetheless, I have included my spec file in the post.

Comment: Thanks lastly could you post the command you are using to launce the pyinstaller e.g. `pyinstaller mybuld.spec` or `pyinstaller -wF myapp.py`.
I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291081/noconsole-not-working-with-pyinstaller